# Retrieve empoly and magers list

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables Employees and Department

```
Table employee columns
empid
name
salary
location

Table department columns
deptno
deptname
empid
mangerid
```

Now I want to retrieve employee and manager list with names.
I tried but i could not retreive

Comment: so far what you have done to retrieve employees and department names

Answer (score 1):

To add some light into it, you can try the following :)
You can remove `GROUP_CONCAT` as well as `GROUP_BY` usual employee by manager results.

Reference:

### [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c813/8)

Sample tables

**EMP**

```
ID  NAME
1   JOHN
2   JIM
3   KATE
4   TIM
5   JANE
```

**DEPT**

```
ID  EID     MID
11  2       1
12  3       2
12  4       1
12  5       2
```

Query with `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT M.NAME AS Manager, GROUP_CONCAT(E.NAME,' ') AS Employee
FROM EMP E
JOIN DEPT D
ON E.ID = D.EID
JOIN EMP M
ON D.MID = M.ID
GROUP BY M.NAME
```

Results:

```
MANAGER     EMPLOYEE
JIM         KATE ,JANE
JOHN        TIM ,JIM
```

Query without `GROUP_CONCAT` and `GROUP_BY`

```
SELECT M.NAME AS Manager, E.NAME AS Employee
FROM EMP E
JOIN DEPT D
ON E.ID = D.EID
JOIN EMP M
ON D.MID = M.ID
```

Results for the query without `GROUP_CONCAT` and `GROUP_BY`

```
MANAGER     EMPLOYEE
JOHN        JIM
JOHN        TIM
JIM         KATE
JIM         JANE
```

Comment: but am getting output as  NAME
1   JOHN jim
2   john jim
3   john tin
4   jim  kate
5   jim  jane

Comment: If you play around with it, you will do really great :) if this solution works for you, please mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `select emp1.name, emp2.name from employee emp1, employee emp2, department dept where emp1.empid=dept.empid and emp2.empid=dept.managerid`

Comment: i want employee and manager names not id's..  manager id also included in employees id